# import scikit-learn module failing

Tags: visual-studio, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I have recently used Anaconda to install scikit-learn, but when I run the following code in Visual Studio for python, it throws an error.

```
import sklearn
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...\Desktop\PY\test_SKL\test_SKL.py", line 1, in <module>
import sklearn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Running "conda update scikit-learn" returns that all packages have already been installed.

All other answers on stackoverflow have not worked for me or are for Linux. I am running Windows 10, and my version of Python is 3.7. I am not running multiple versions of Python, as the most commonly occurring source of this problem indicates. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Just as afterthought, sklearn has downloaded properly, since I can use it in the Spyder IDE that comes with Anaconda. My problem is that Visual Studio can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in visual studio your python executable to take this of your conda environment. In linux this one is in conda_dir/envs/yourenv/bin, I think it can be the same in windows.